# How to get those records that contains every items mentioned in where clause

Tags: sql-server

I have a table (mentioned below):

```
CityId  StoreId DeviceId    Tags
1234    101     0           Online
1234    101     2           Online
1234    101     3           Online
1234    101     3           Error
1234    101     4           Online
1234    101     5           Online
1234    101     5           InActive
1234    101     6           Online
1234    101     6           InActive
```

I want those records which have both the tags "Online" and "InActive".

The output which is expected is:

```
CityId  StoreId DeviceId    Tags
1234    101     5           Online
1234    101     5           InActive
1234    101     6           Online
1234    101     6           InActive
```

Queries I was trying are: Query 1 gives no result and Query 2 gives all other records where only "Online" is available.

Query 1:

```
where <some_other_conditions> and (Tags = 'Online' and Tags = 'InActive')
```

Query 2:

```
where <some_other_conditions> and (Tags = 'Online' or Tags = 'InActive')
```

Comment: Thank you @Zhorov for correct formatting

Comment: If you have a row `1234    101 6   Error`, what will be the expected output?

Comment: Thank you all of you for your kind inputs and time for my ask. I have marked @forpas's response as accepted because it make my query to give expected output with very minimal changes in my existing query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With EXISTS:

```
select t.* from tablename t
where t.tags in ('Online', 'Inactive')
and exists (
  select 1 from tablename
  where tags in ('Online', 'Inactive') and
  cityid = t.cityid and storeid = t.storeid and deviceid = t.deviceid and tags <> t.tags
)
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=e300885e0511b8b08ce22b0f2800747f).
Results:

```
> cityid | storeid | deviceid | tags    
> -----: | ------: | -------: | :-------
>   1234 |     101 |        5 | Online  
>   1234 |     101 |        5 | InActive
>   1234 |     101 |        6 | Online  
>   1234 |     101 |        6 | InActive
```

Answer (score 1):

One possible approach is to use windowed `SUM()` and `COUNT()`, without `ORDER BY` caluse, and then use the appropriate `WHERE` clause:

Data:

```
CREATE TABLE #Data (
    CityId int,
    StoreId int,
    DeviceId int,    
    Tags varchar(10)
)
INSERT INTO #Data 
   (CityId, StoreId, DeviceId, Tags)
VALUES
    (1234, 101, 0, 'Online'),
    (1234, 101, 2, 'Online'),
    (1234, 101, 3, 'Online'),
    (1234, 101, 3, 'Error'),
    (1234, 101, 4, 'Online'),
    (1234, 101, 5, 'Online'),
    (1234, 101, 5, 'InActive'),
    (1234, 101, 6, 'Error'),
    (1234, 101, 6, 'Online'),
    (1234, 101, 6, 'InActive')
```

Statement:

```
SELECT CityId, StoreId, DeviceId, Tags
FROM (
    SELECT 
        *,
        SUM(CASE WHEN Tags = 'Online' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) OVER (PARTITION BY CityId, StoreId, DeviceId) AS OnlineCount,
        SUM(CASE WHEN Tags = 'InActive' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) OVER (PARTITION BY CityId, StoreId, DeviceId) AS InActiveCount,
        COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY CityId, StoreId, DeviceId) AS TotalCount
    FROm #Data
) t
WHERE
    (OnlineCount = 1) AND (InActiveCount = 1) AND (Tags = 'Online' OR Tags = 'InActive')
```

Output:

```
--------------------------------
CityId  StoreId DeviceId    Tags
--------------------------------
1234    101     5           Online
1234    101     5           InActive
1234    101     6           Online
1234    101     6           InActive
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this may be it helpful.

```
    SELECT * FROM city WHERE CONCAT(CityId,StoreId ,DeviceId) in
    (
        SELECT CONCAT(CityId,StoreId ,DeviceId) 
            from (
                    SELECT CityId,  StoreId , DeviceId   , Tags, ROW_NUMBER()over(partition by CityId,  StoreId , DeviceId order by CityId,  StoreId,   DeviceId ) rnk
                        FROM city)a
            WHERE (tags ='online' or tags ='InActive')
    and rnk>=2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope Can Help You

```
Select * Into #DATA From (
    Select '1234' [CityID], '101' [StoreID],  '0' [DeviceID], 'Online' [Tags] Union All
    Select '1234' [CityID], '101' [StoreID],  '2' [DeviceID], 'Online' [Tags] Union All
    Select '1234' [CityID], '101' [StoreID],  '3' [DeviceID], 'Online' [Tags] Union All
    Select '1234' [CityID], '101' [StoreID],  '3' [DeviceID], 'Error' [Tags] Union All
    Select '1234' [CityID], '101' [StoreID],  '4' [DeviceID], 'Online' [Tags] Union All
    Select '1234' [CityID], '101' [StoreID],  '5' [DeviceID], 'Online' [Tags] Union All
    Select '1234' [CityID], '101' [StoreID],  '5' [DeviceID], 'InActive' [Tags] Union All
    Select '1234' [CityID], '101' [StoreID],  '6' [DeviceID], 'Online' [Tags] Union All
    Select '1234' [CityID], '101' [StoreID],  '6' [DeviceID], 'InActive' [Tags] 
) A

Select * From #DATA D
Left Join (
    Select 
        CityID, StoreID, DeviceID, Count(*) [Total] 
    From #DATA
    Where Tags In ('OnLine','InActive')
    Group By CityID, StoreID, DeviceID
    Having Count(*) = 2
) T On D.CityID = T.CityID And D. StoreID = T. StoreID And D. DeviceID = T. DeviceID 
Where T.CityID Is Not Null
```

Result :

[image]